# Disable a specific key on a specific keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-event

I suspect this can't be done, but I would like to disable a specific key (namely '6' on the top row) on a specific keyboard (namely my laptop internal keyboard). The key is spamming 6s but is otherwise working (and I've ordered a replacement but it will take a long time due to location).
I am mostly using a USB keyboard but it is a pain to disable an entire keyboard (using xinput --float) just for one key.

So: is it possible to disable a specific key on a specific keyboard? I am using Kubuntu 19.10 although I suspect that is not important for this.

Comment: It should be possible, try to intercept first keyboard code, and then rewrite the value.
These are your friends: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xev and https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmodmap

Comment: But how do you do that for a _specific_ keyboard i.e. only disable it on my laptop keyboard and not on my USB keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

> Use xev to find the keycode of the 6 key on your keyboard, "on mine it is 15". Then use `xmodmap -e "keycode 15 = "` where 15 is the number you found with xev. This will map that key to nothing. If that ends up not being persistent after reboot add that command to your startup apps.

If wanting for just one keyboard:

- Install xkbcomp 1.2.0
- Use `xinput list` find the specific keyboard id
- Find the keycode for the key with `xev`.

FURTHER instructions at the link... https://superuser.com/a/869064/964775

- To undo this operation you must remember or write down what xev gave you for the key and then just xmodmap it back to that.
- I am fairly certain you could add this to your .profile or .bashrc file and have it be set for all terminals as well.

Comment: I ended up doing it a slightly different way as this method didn't work for some reason, but got me on the right track :)
Did something like: https://miek.nl/2014/october/28/xmodmap-is-dead/ but using the -i (remote_id) flag.

Comment: It would be good to add a way to undo the change.

Comment: I have the issue with spamming <. It seems to be keycode 94. Interestingly, `xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = "` seems not to have any effect (Ubuntu 20.04, Thinkpad T460p)

Comment: It seems to work only for the current terminal. I also tried `xmodmap -e 'keycode 94=NoSymbol'`